# API Response filecontent is Empty on Lucee server

Tags: api, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee, http-parameters

When i call the canadaPost api in Coldfusion server that is giving the expected response. But when i Use the same call in Lucee server, It throws the message fail. The response header is "Oracle-iPlanet-Web-Server/7.0" for both servers. But the response mimetype is "application/octet-stream" in Lucee server and "application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml" in coldfusion server.

Is that the cause of the issue? Please give your suggestion about this.

Here is my code:

```
<cfset local.url = "https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price">

<cfhttp url="#local.url#" method="post" result="httpResponse" username="#variables.username#" password="#variables.password#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(xmlRequest)#"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml">
</cfhttp>
```

Attached screenshot which is taken on Lucee server:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does the call succeed, ie 200 OK or are you getting an error? Can you post a dump of the response?

Comment: @Leigh Attached the lucee server response screenshot.

Comment: Is it an SSL call as cfSimplicity mentioned? (The dump suggests no..)

Comment: Yes, It is an SSL call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the file content value by changed the cfhttpparam type "xml" to "body".

**My Fix:**

```
<cfset local.url = "https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price">
<cfhttp url="#local.url#" method="post" result="httpResponse" username="#variables.username#" password="#variables.password#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#trim(xmlRequest)#"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml">
</cfhttp>
```

Thank you guyz..

Comment: Is that working without the Authorization header cfhttparam?

Comment: Yes CfSimplicity. It is working without the Authorization header cfhttpparam.

Comment: Does that particular API call actually require Authorization (i.e. the username and password)?

Comment: Yes Cfsimplicity, that is required.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Lucee (and previously Railo) whereby the username and password attributes specified in `<cfhttp>` are not sent when using SSL.

To work around it you can send the Authorization header using `<cfhttpparam>` as follows:

```
<cfhttp url="#local.url#" method="post" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim(xmlRequest)#"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic #ToBase64( variables.username & ':' & variables.password )#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Yet i facing the same issue when using the Authorization header in <cfhttpparam>.